# HTML formating with Notepad++ Pretty print

Tags: html, xml, notepad++, pretty-print

Trying to format `HTML` using `Pretty print` from `Notepad++`.

Why  `</div>` tag is placed most right side? And next section is placed even more to right.

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="aaa" class="clsButton">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="button1" value="aaa1" class="clsButton">
        </div>
```

According to my understanding both sections should be placed in the same level:

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="aaa" class="clsButton">
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button1" value="aaa1" class="clsButton">
</div>
```

I am wrong?

Comment: did you try this http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/auto-indentation-plugin-for-notepad

Answer (score 5):

Use XML tools

Run Notepad++ and click menu "Plugins" > "Plugin Manager" > "Show plugin manager" You see the "Plugin Manager" window showing up.

Find "XML Tools" in the "Available" list and make it checked. Then click "Install" to finish adding "XML Tools" to Notepad++.

Click menu "Plugins" > "XML Tools". You see a list of XML Tools commands showing up.